# unable to create an array of Objects in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

This is a simple question and have done this many time but now I am unable to make an array of objects. I naturally googled and the below is what they had too.

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

    private let data: User[] = [
        {ssn: "146-89-5656", userId: 'jochampa', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "777-88-1000", userId: 'teddyBear', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "132-40-4000", userId: 'Josh', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "123-56-6000", userId: 'Kori', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "777-98-7000", userId: 'Dummy', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "899-19-2200", userId: 'Drew', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "021-69-2222", userId: 'Ken', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "589-47-9999", userId: 'Justin', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "146-89-5656", userId: 'jochampa', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "777-88-1000", userId: 'teddyBear', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "132-40-4000", userId: 'Josh', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "123-56-6000", userId: 'Kori', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "777-98-7000", userId: 'Dummy', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "899-19-2200", userId: 'Drew', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "021-69-2222", userId: 'Ken', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
        {ssn: "589-47-9999", userId: 'Justin', office: 'AMB', role: 'admin'},
    ];
```

But I get an error when I hover over it saying `ERROR TS1005 expected =`

User object:

```
export class User {
    ssn:string;
    userId:string;
    lastName:string;
    office:string;
    role:string;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should not use `let` for assignment and you are missing `lastName` in the `User` object. You can make `lastName` optional by defining it as `lastName?:string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is the right way to write this `private let data: User[] =..` 
Is this a field or a local variable?

If it's a field then it should be

```
private data: User[] = ..
```

So you can access it in your class with `this.data`

else it should be inside a `contstructor`, method or outside of the `@Injectable`

Also the objects don't have the `lastName` property.

Comment: I tried that too, please see the picture I just added.

Comment: @Drew1208 Is it the same error? Did you compile the ts? Also the objects don't have the `lastName` property

Comment: It was the lastName. I need to step away for a while.